# How to use XPath to scrape javascript website values

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape (in python) the savings interest rate from [this website](https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/banking/online-savings/account/#:%7E:text=Yield%20Savings%20(HYSA)-,3.30%25,-APY) using the value's xpath variable.

I've tried everything: beautifulsoup, selenium, etree, etc. I've been able to scrape a few other websites successfully. However, this site and many others are giving me fits. I'd love a solution that can scrape info from several sites regardless of their formatting using xpath variables.

My current attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service(executable_path="/chromedriver")
options = Options()
options.add_argument(' — incognito')
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

url = 'https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/banking/online-savings/account/'
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hysa-apy-2"]')
print(element.text)
if element.text == "":
    print("Error: Element text is empty")

driver.quit()
```

Comment: _giving me fits_  Instead of making vague statements like this, it would be much more productive if you said what this code **actually does**.  Does it produce an error?  Does it produce unexpected output?

Comment: It returns an empty string.

Comment: If you know the element id, it's better to use that instead of the xpath.  `find_element(By.ID,'hysa-apy-2')`

Comment: I've tried you code snippet, it worked with return `3.30% APY` text, maybe you need `wait`, it seem like the element found but the text not yet load.

Comment: Do you have an example? I've tried several WebDriverWait commands, but I've never had it return '3.30% APY' ever.

Comment: I've also tried find_element by ID. It also produces an empty string for me.

Comment: An answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

The interest rates are written inside span elements. All span elements which contain interest rates share the same `class` `heading-6`. But bear in mind, the result returns two span elements for each interest rate, each element for a different viewport.

The xpath selector:

```
'//span[@class="heading-6"]'
```

[image]

You can also get elements by `containing text APY`:

```
'//span[contains(., "APY")]'
```

[image]
But this selector looks for all span elements in the DOM that contain word `APY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you find unique id, it is recommended to be priority, like this :`find_element(By.ID,'hysa-apy-2')` like @John Gordon comment.

But sometimes when the element found, the text not yet load.

Use xpath with add this logic `and text()!=""`

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="hysa-apy-2" and text()!=""]')))
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it also results in an empty string...

Comment: Hmmm can you try with `.visibility_of_element_located`? @jasonlovesplanes

Comment: Still nothing. It seems I get an empty string or an error no matter what I do.